# Grouping a list of sublists by some of the values in each sublist

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, comparison

I have a dictionary containing lists. For example,

```
{1: [[sender11, receiver11, text11, address11]], 
 2: [[sender21, receiver21, text21, address21], [sender22, receiver22, text22, address22]], 
 3: [[sender31, receiver31, text31, address31], [sender32, receiver32, text32, address32], [sender33, receiver33, text33, address33]]
 4: [[sender41, receiver41, text41, address41], [sender42, receiver42, text42, address42], [sender43, receiver43, text43, address43], [sender44, receiver44, text44, address44]]}
```

What I want to do is, for dictionary elements that contain a list with 2 or more elements (i.e. `dict[2]`, `dict[3]` and `dict[4]` in this example), I do a comparison of the `sender, receiver, text` for each list value. For each group of list values with the same `sender, receiver, text`, I'll do something.

So for example, in `dict[3]`, if `sender31, receiver31, text31` are the same values as `sender32, receiver32, text32` and `sender33, receiver33, text33`, then I'll do something with all 3 list values.

Say in `dict[4]`, if `sender41, receiver41, text41` are the same values as `sender42, receiver42, text42`, while `sender43, receiver43, text43` are the same values as `sender44, receiver44, text44`, but different from `sender41, receiver41, text41`, then I'll work on these 2 groups separately.

I wrote a Python script that pretty much brute force compares the values of `sender21, receiver21, text21` and `sender22, receiver22, text22`, i.e.

```
if sender21 == sender22 and receiver21 == receiver22 and text21 == text22:
   # Do something
```

This isn't efficient as it only works for 2 list values, but I don't know how I should implement this such that it works for any number of list values greater than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is the obvious way to go here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def collate(seq):
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for subseq in seq:
        groups[tuple(subseq[:3])].append(subseq[3])
    return groups
```

Depending on your actual data, you might replace `tuple(subseq[:3])` in the function above with e.g. `(subseq[1], subseq[4], subseq[5])`, or the appended `subseq[3]` with `subseq` itself ... that'll depend on what you're doing with the data.

The key has to be a tuple rather than a list, though, because keys must be immutable.

Example:

```
>>> data = [
...     ['S1', 'R1', 'T1', 'A3'],
...     ['S2', 'R2', 'T2', 'A4'],
...     ['S1', 'R1', 'T1', 'A5'],
...     ['S2', 'R2', 'T2', 'A6']
... ]
```

```
>>> collate(data)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
    ('S2', 'R2', 'T2'): ['A4', 'A6'],
    ('S1', 'R1', 'T1'): ['A3', 'A5']
})
```

You can work with this just as you would any other dictionary, e.g.

```
>>> for (sender, receiver, text), addresses in collate(data).items():
...     print sender, receiver, text
...     print '|'.join(addresses)
...     print
... 
S2 R2 T2
A4|A6

S1 R1 T1
A3|A5
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well. However, what if now, instead of matching exactly for `(sender, receiver, text)`, I want `(sender, receiver, text)` and `(receiver, sender, text)` to be in the same group, i.e. the order of sender/receiver does not matter? Is this possible? Do I need to hash it?

Comment: The collection type that's a) immutable and b) doesn't care about order is a `frozenset`, so something like `groups[frozenset(subseq[:2]), subseq[2]].append(subseq[3])` sounds about right - tweak as necessary.

Comment: By the way, this is the kind of thing that you should either know or be able to quickly find out from the docs in order to be an effective programmer. Reading https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html over and over again until you just *know* the standard types will repay your effort massively in the long run.